# Extracting wide chars w/ attributes in ncurses

Tags: c++, c, ncurses, curses

*[Please note I am using `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1` and `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")`.]*

Curses includes various functions for extracting characters from the screen; they can be divided into those which grab just the text and those which grab the text plus attributes (bold, color, etc.).  The former use `wchar_t` (or `char`) and the latter curses' own `chtype`.

There are constants to mask a `chtype` to get just the character or just the attributes -- `A_CHARTEXT` and `A_ATTRIBUTES`.  However, from the value of these, it is easy to see that there will be collisions with `wchar_t` values over 255.  `A_ATTRIBUTES` is 64-bits and only the lower 8 are unset.

If the base type internally is `chtype`, this would mean ncurses was unworkable with most of unicode, but it isn't -- you can use hardcoded strings in UTF-8 source and write them out with attributes no problem.  Where it gets interesting is getting them back again.

```
wchar_t s[] = "\412";
```

This character has a value of 266 and displays as `Ċ`.  However, when extracted into a `chtype` using, e.g., `mvwinchnstr()`, it is exactly the same as a space (10) with the `COLOR_PAIR(1)` attribute (256) set.  And in fact, if you take the extracted `chtype` and redisplay it, you get just that -- a space with `COLOR_PAIR(1)` set.

But if you extract it instead into a `wchar_t` with, e.g. `mvwinnwstr()`, it's correct, as is a colored space.  The problem with this, of course, is that the attributes are gone.  This implies the attributes are being masked out correctly, *which is demonstrably impossible with a `chtype`,* since a `chtype` for both of these has the same value (266). In other words, the internal representation is **obviously niether a `chtype` nor a `wchar_t`.**

I do not use ncurses much, and I notice there are other curses implementations (e.g. [Oracle's](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36880/mvwinwchstr-3curses.html)) with functions that imply the `chtype` there *might* not have this problem.  In any case, is there a way w/ ncurses to unambiguously extract wide chars together with their attributes?

*[I've tagged this C and C++ since it is applicable in both contexts.]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more complicated than that.  But briefly:

- In the SVr4 implementation, there was just `chtype`.
- X/Open work for standardization added on the multibyte characters, represented in `cchar_t`.
- Not blatantly obvious in the X/Open documentation, but seen in the corresponding Unix implementations, the `chtype` and `cchar_t` were not envisioned as possibly different views of the same data.  You can *only* make 8-bit encodings with the former.
- Not many applications really delve into Unix implementations to make it apparent (in fact, at least one vendor's XPG4 implementation never worked well enough to do useful testing — so much for the state of the art).
- The integration (or lack of same) was overlooked in ncurses, where it seemed a natural thing to do.
- ncurses accepts multibyte strings in `addstr` (none of the Unix's do).
- ncurses *attempts* to provide the same information via either style of interface which was set via the other.
- There are obviously limitations: `chtype` corresponds to a single cell on the screen, and can hold only an 8-bit character.  Interfaces such as [`winnstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_instr.3x.html) which return a string will work within that constraint.  The [`winchnstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inchstr.3x.html) function does return an array of `chtype` values.
- If you want the *attributes* for a cell which is *not* an 8-bit character, you are best off by retrieving it via the analogous [`win_wchnstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_in_wchstr.3x.html)